# Meaning of ;-symbol in math

Tags: functions, notation

Learning about the formal definition of the derivativ, I am asked to find the derivative at the indicated point from the graph of the function.

However in the following problems, I do not understand what the ";"-symbol mean

f(x)=5;x=1

f(x)=4x-3;x=-1

Of course the meaning of ; is something I should remember, but any help would be much appreciated as google search and lists of mathematical symbols didn't help!

Comment: Where did you find such a notation...?

Comment: My previous guess at the meaning was wrong, so I deleted that comment.  The question is asking you to calculate the derivative of the function that's written before the semicolon and then to evaluate that derivative at the value of $x$ that's written after the semicolon.

Comment: Following @AndreasBlass I suspect that the ";" is not mathematical but belongs to the "surrounding" natural language

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it want the derivative of the given function at the point with a given $x$. So $f(x)=5 ; x=1$ means $f'(1)$ where $f'$ is the derivative of $f(x)=5$, and $f(x)=4x-3 ; x=-1$ means $f'(-1)$ where $f'$ is the derivative of $f(x)=4x-3$.

So,here, the symbol ''$;$'' is not really a mathematical symbol, but simply a punctuation mark.